# How to catch exception if flexQueue is full when using System.scheduleBatch

Tags: batch, governorlimits, schedulebatch

What happens to a batch class which is scheduled to be executed by

```
System.scheduleBatch(batchableClass, batchClassName, 1, 50);
```

The batch class gets scheduled as a Schedulable Job after a minute.
Lets assume that flex queue is always full, or at the point when Salesforce tries to execute the Batch Job the flex queue is full to 100 and there are 5 other batch job processing in the system.

Here salesforce wont be able to execute the batch job. Where to catch that exception and retry this job.

Comment: Is this a hypothetical question, or an actual issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to handle this scenario since the code that calls `Database.executeBatch` is entirely within the platform and debug logged enablement and scraping is not practical for production code.

Comment: @sfdcfox This is indeed a hypothetical question. But can this ever happen?

Comment: Can we use `batchapexerrorevent` here? Will that get raised?